# OutOfMemoryException:java heap space

Tags: java, swing

I have develop a project which has more than 3000 source files; when I want to run my project after few minutes it gives me error like `java.lang.OutOfMemoryException: java heap space`. I also increased the memory of my project by right clicking and VM option I gave the 1024MB I have two 2gb on my PC.

Comment: Do you know the code works with more memory?
Your project could just be buggy and have memory leaks or infinite recursion.

Comment: Or maybe the code needs large buffers, err, arrays. Or maybe it's got some tuneable parameter to control how much it grabs. 3000 classes isn't all that much. Neither is 2GB memory these days…

Comment: did you checked heap memory size?

Comment: More than 3000 source files? Does this happen during *compile time*?

Comment: What is exactly that you need? You should pinpoint what is allocating memory in your app. Maybe what is not clear is _how_ to find this. Can you say something about the nature of your project other than how many source files it has? Might be helpful to suggest what to investigate.

Comment: Akash Shinde this happen when i want to clean and build my project and i am using NetBeans for developing this application and also SQL server-2008 for database please guid me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you likely know you can increase the JVM's memory using `java -Xms<initial heap size> -Xmx<maximum heap size>`.

However this just delays the issue as there is likely a place in your application where is memory is leaking causing the heap overflow. I suggest you use a tool like [Netbeans Profiler](https://profiler.netbeans.org/) which will help you find out where the memory leak is occurring. Netbeans Profiler will allow you to see where objects are created, where garbage collection occurs, etc.

Comment: How can i find the leakage of memory i am using NetBeans for my project. This problem occur when i want to clean and build the project, its give the outOfMemory error. please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the application just allocates a lot of memory or there is an actual leak.  My approach would be to use a memory analyzer such as [Eclipse MAT](https://eclipse.org/mat/) to see what objects are taking up the most memory.

If they all seem valid then you probably need to increase the heap size space.  Though I had worked with 5000+ class web app projects with 512MB heap, so I wouldn't doubt that it was a memory leak.

You should also look for instances of `ByteArrayOutputStream` in your code, they tend to take up a large chunk of memory as well.